# GAE Datastore: How to set filter on db.DateTimeProperty()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Hi I am new to GAE and Python and coming from PHP and MySQL background. 
Apologies if my question is naive and without enough homework.

In my app I have many masters and I want to display these masters one by one(an option to switch the view into list mode).

All my master models have an attribute called ts and on saving it is automatically populated with the current timestamp.

I have a method get_rec on my master class where it defaults to fetching the last saved record. On clicking the navigation buttons the system is supposed to take the prev or next. In order to achieve this I write this piece of code

```
q = db.Query(modl)
if pos == "prev" :
    #ts is a string returned by JSON as 2012-07-03T14:19:36.817000
    q.filter("ts <", ts.replace("T", " "))
    q.order('-ts')
elif pos == "next" :
    q.filter("ts >", ts.replace("T", " "))
    q.order('ts')
else :
    q.order('-ts')
res = q.fetch(1)
return simplejson.dumps(res, cls=jsonEncoder)
```

But the data object returned is always the last record.
BTW the json sent ts has a T in front of the time, whereas on data viewer console, I cannot find any T but a space instead. I tried replacing the T with a space. Shall I pass the date object as datetime.datetime() instead of date string?

Am I missing something here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok. It is my mistake. MySQL always stores datetime as string and a string comparison is easy to achieve but not on datastore. As I originally doubted that the datetime is stored as python date object and I need to pass this with datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'). The version with GAE does not support .%f which is another issue we can easily sort it out with other SO question and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert string into datetime - **filter** with not work with strings I think so.

Read 1st help http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Use strftime and strptime (format or parse) http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Please vote for answer!

Comment: Thanks. GAE datastore is so different from traditional SQL and it takes some time to adjust ourselves to it. Realized this and corrected my code.